# What's the right way to use eBPF's "bpf_current_task_under_cgroup" and other helper functions on Android?

Tags: android, clang, hook, helper, ebpf

Wish you a nice day first.

Recently I started to learn using eBPF on Android. Actually I am a beginner of Android APP development. Things are not bad at first, and I successfully built up a demo. But when I started to try other eBPF helper functions, my program can not pass the verification of the compiler, and I wonder what's the right way to use those helpers on Android. The details are as follows.

First, let me show the demo which can work normally.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <bpf_helpers.h>

DEFINE_BPF_MAP(cpu_pid_map, ARRAY, int, uint32_t, 1024);


struct switch_args {
    unsigned long long ignore;
    char prev_comm[16];
    int prev_pid;
    int prev_prio;
    long long prev_state;
    char next_comm[16];
    int next_pid;
    int next_prio;
};

DEFINE_BPF_PROG("tracepoint/sched/sched_switch", AID_ROOT, AID_SYSTEM, tp_sched_switch) (struct switch_args* args) {
    int key;
    uint32_t val;

    key = bpf_get_smp_processor_id();
    val = args->next_pid;


    bpf_cpu_pid_map_update_elem(&key, &val, BPF_ANY);
    return 0;
}
LICENSE("Apache 2.0");
```

The above code can work well, but actually I do not understand why there the function `bpf_cpu_pid_map_update_elem` contains the name of the defined BPF map "cpu_pid_map". The original function is defined as `long bpf_map_update_elem(struct bpf_map *map, const void *key, const void *value, u64 flags)`, which can be found at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html

I further tried the following program.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <bpf_helpers.h>

//DEFINE_BPF_MAP(cpu_pid_map, ARRAY, int, uint32_t, 1024);

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") cpu_pid_map = {
    .type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
    .key_size=sizeof(int),
    .value_size=sizeof(uint32_t),
    .max_entries=1024,
};

//DEFINE_BPF_MAP(CgroupMap, CGROUP_ARRAY, uint32_t, uint32_t, 1);

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") cgroup_map = {
    .type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_CGROUP_ARRAY,
    .key_size=sizeof(uint32_t),
    .value_size=sizeof(uint32_t),
    .max_entries=1,
};



const volatile bool filter_cg = false;


struct switch_args {
    unsigned long long ignore;
    char prev_comm[16];
    int prev_pid;
    int prev_prio;
    long long prev_state;
    char next_comm[16];
    int next_pid;
    int next_prio;
};

// SEC("tracepoint/sched/sched_switch")
DEFINE_BPF_PROG("tracepoint/sched/sched_switch", AID_ROOT, AID_SYSTEM, tp_sched_switch) (struct switch_args* args) {
// int tp_sched_switch(struct switch_args* args) {
    int key;
    uint32_t val;

    key = bpf_get_smp_processor_id();
    val = args->next_pid;

    if (filter_cg && !bpf_current_task_under_cgroup(&cgroup_map, 0))
        return 0;

    bpf_map_update_elem(&cpu_pid_map, &key, &val, BPF_ANY);
    return 0;
}

// char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
LICENSE("Apache 2.0");
```

In this program, I added a cgroup_map and "bpf_current_task_under_cgroup(&cgroup_map, 0)" to test the funtion. Also, I use `bpf_map_update_elem(&cpu_pid_map, &key, &val, BPF_ANY)` to replace the older one.

Unfortunately, both function didn't pass the verification of the Clang compiler. The compiler shows that `Implicit declaration of function "xxx" is invalid in C99`, where "xxx" refers to the name of those two helper functions.

I feel confused about this, and now I haven't found out how to fix this problem.

I refered to the time_in_state.c program in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bpfprogs/+/482dfa1ca63eb209866ff3a7b3aeb3daada7b4e1/time_in_state.c , which is given by the official document. It uses `bpf_map_update_elem(&cpu_freq, &cpu, &new, BPF_ANY)`, but similar function does not work on my Android.

Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!